# How to add a count in a custom tab in a Buddypress group

Tags: buddypress

I create a new tab in my Buddypress groups like so:

```
bp_core_new_subnav_item( array( 
    'name' => "new tab <span>$count</span>",
    'slug' => 'namings', 
    'parent_url' => $group_link, 
    'parent_slug' => $bp->groups->current_group->slug,
    'screen_function' => 'bp_group_namings', 
    'position' => 50, 
    'user_has_access' => $user_access, 
    'item_css_id' => 'namings' 
));
```

The `$count` variable has a value. But, the span is consistently removed from the tab title.

How to get a count in the tab title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the BP Nouveau templates, correct? Span tag works fine in the Legacy templates.

In Nouveau, all links are stripped of span tags. 
See the calls to `function _bp_strip_spans_from_title` and functions like `bp_nouveau_get_nav_link_text` in `buddypress\bp-templates\bp-nouveau\includes\template-tags.php`.

So remove your span tag from the create subnav item function.

Instead, in Nouveau, use 2 filters for adding a count item.

So something like:

```
function masta_add_namings_count( $count, $nav_item, $displayed_nav ) {

    if ( $displayed_nav == 'groups' ) {

        if ( $nav_item->slug == 'namings' ) {

            $count = true;

        }

    }

    return $count;

}
add_filter( 'bp_nouveau_nav_has_count', 'masta_add_namings_count', 99, 3 );


function masta_add_namings_count_int( $count, $nav_item, $displayed_nav ) {

    if ( $displayed_nav == 'groups' ) {

        if ( $nav_item->slug == 'namings' ) {

            $group_id = bp_get_current_group_id();

            $count = 666; // pass the group_id to a function that returns the proper count

        }

    }

    return $count;

}
add_filter( 'bp_nouveau_get_nav_count', 'masta_add_namings_count_int', 99, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks. This did not work. Not in my child theme, not in the 2019 theme. Here, too, the span with the count is removed.

Comment: Are you using a plugin or other code to restrict tags?  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses

Comment: Not knowingly. I've deactivated all plugins, except Buddypress, ACF Pro and CPT UI. But, still, no number in the tab. Oddly, I also was using the Events Manager plugin, and that plugin *is* able to get a number in the tab.

Comment: Are you using the BP Nouveau templates?  See edited answer.

Comment: I am indeed. This worked. Thanks. Can I read up somewhere about the rationalisation to so radically change this aspect of buddypress?

Comment: I'm not aware of any written rationalization.  The template pack choices are meant to be very different.  Makes writing distributed code that much harder.  Take a look at this fork of BP...  Scroll down to link: https://www.buddyboss.com/pricing/